# How to show the infowindow for marker in google map street view

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have the following query regarding this.

1) I have shown some marker with their infowindow in the map and we have "street view" link in the infowindow popup.

2) When we click on the street view link of each infowindow then we want to display the street view within the same div.

3) We are successfully done the code to display the street view and its also display the corresponding marker but my problem is that when i am trying to click that marker then their corresponding popup is not open.

So anyone has the idea how we can remain the infobox in the streetview as in the normal map view.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("<map-div>"), myOptions);
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
                marker, i;
            for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i]['latitude'], markers[i]['longitude']),
                    map: map
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                    return function () {
                        infowindow.setContent(markers[i]['name']);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, i));
            }
```